# Magento 2.4.3 Stock Problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

I have a problem with qtys when I'm trying to order the same product more than one qty.

Example I have a T-Shirt with size: Small and qtys : 2

When I'm trying to order this products with 2 qtys in the backend the qtys reduced only one time. In product shows qty 1 but I have order 2 qtys. Inside the order shows correct 2 times the product and the total price is correct.

I have seen that in the sales_order_item table it has write only one time the simple product. ( The configurable product is two times but the simple only one time. )

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks!

Ps: Magento V. 2.4.3, MSI Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you mentioned that Multi-Source Inventory (MSI) is disabled, you should check your inventory settings. Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory and review the settings there, especially "Backorders" and "Manage Stock." Make sure they are set according to your requirements.
2. Then Reindex

Comment: I have already checked and everything is fine! The Backorder is off and the Manage Stock is Yes. The weird is that this problem appears only in configurable products. If I order a simple product 2 times the stock reduced correct.

Comment: Can you explain or share screenshot of error

Comment: The problem is when I'm buying an associate simple product from configurable product more than 1 qty. I add 3 times the same product in the cart ( T-shirt red size small ) in the checkout I see correct the 3 products and correct the total amount but when I place the order the stock from the product t-shirt red size small reduce 1 time not 3 times. Also if I cancel the order it's return 1 qty back to stock not 3 qtys. Ps: In order in the backend I see correct the 3 products.

Comment: Have you checked that in the backend you create combo code?

Comment: Please check settings as same as: https://prnt.sc/OmKMAxh3Q7E6

Comment: It's a simple product associated to a configurable product. And the settings are as you show me.

Comment: Then please share a screenshot of the coding add to cart page